# Integrating multimedia with LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

According to the LibGDX web page:

> Android applications can have multiple activities. Libgdx games should usually only consist of a single activity. Different screens of the game are implemented within libgdx, not as separate activities. The reason for this is that creating a new Activity also implies creating a new OpenGL context, which is time consuming and also means that all graphical resources have to be reloaded.

However, this isn't impossible to do - just undesirable.

I'm building an app that is designed to hold a few games built in LibGDX, as well as some information alongside it - video/audio, text with illustrations, and so on, describing the development of the games.

Is it a better idea to build this as a native android application that launches and tears down LibGDX whenever the user wants to play a game? Or should I write the entire app through LibGDX and do try and do the non-game stuff using UI libraries and so on?

I'm sorry I can't nail this down to a more specific question. I'm really interested to know before I embark down the wrong road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The consensus in a linked Reddit thread [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/xdv1l/should_i_go_alllibgdx_or_integrate_it_into_a/) is that setting up and tearing down a LibGDX activity isn't such a huge overhead, particularly if the games are small (which they are in my case).

I'm going to opt for this solution, and simply shut down the activity whenever the user stops playing a game.